# Grafana exclude UtcTime records

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have two tables, one with all records with one column with time in UTC, and second table where I could add entries like:

| Time Start | Time End | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-02 15:00:00 | 2022-02-02 19:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-04-02 15:00:00 | 2022-10-10 15:00:00 | 2 |

all entries from second table are possible to select from variable dropdown.
I'm using SQL data source. I could not configure properly Query.

Already I was thinking about using something like Where UTCTime Not like ... but I don't have any idea how to implement it from multiple entries from variable list (which is not fixed; I can select one entry to exclude or several).

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about. What are trying to do? How are dashboard variables involved in all of this? Please rewrite this question and show clearly what you have and what you want to achieve.